# How to remove Aptana context menu in FireFox?

Tags: aptana3

I've installed Aptana Sstudio 3. A fewhours later I uninstalled it. Ever since, I have a context menu in FireFox that points to Aptana Studio. How do I remove that context menu?

Thanks.

PS: This is really irritating. I expected a program to remove all traces of itself when uninstalled and not leave all sorts of residual junk in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in FF. Go to configure editors and delete Aptana from the list.